# FX Hull-White model

Tags: fx, hullwhite

A model for FX, presented in *Interest Rate Models*, Brigo and Mercurio (2006), has the following dynamics:
\begin{align}
dr_t^d&= \lambda_d(\theta_d(t)-r_t^d)dt+\eta_d dW_t^d\\
dr_t^f&= [\lambda_d(\theta_d(t)-r_t^d)-\eta_f\rho_{S,f}\sigma]dt+\eta_f dW_t^f\\
\frac{dS_t}{S_t}& =(r_t^d-r_t^f)dt +\sigma dW_t^S
\end{align}
where $S_t$ is the spot exchange rate, the brownian motions are defined under the domestic measure and $\rho_{S,f}$ is the instantaneous correlation of $W_t^S$ and $W_t^f$.

The covered interest parity is given by the no arbitrage argument, hence the forward exchange rate is $F_t(T)=S_t\frac{P_t^f(t,T)}{P_t^d(t,T)}$ with  $P_t(t,T)$ the prices of the ZCBs.

Is the uncovered interest parity also respected by the model?

$$E_t[S_T]=?F_t(T)$$

Comment: What do you mean the covered or uncovered interest parity?

Comment: covered interest parity: $F_t(T)=S_t\frac{P_t^f(t,T)}{P_t^d(t,T)}$

uncovered interest parity: $E_t[S_T]=F_t(T)$

Comment: I am unable to locate the page from which you extracted these equations. Could you please let me know if you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be the forward exchange rate determined at time $t$ for maturity $T$. Then the payoff at time $T$ is given by $S_T-K$, which has zero value at time $t$. Let $Q$ and $Q^f$ be the respective domestic and foreign risk-neutral measures, and $E^Q$ and $E^{Q^f}$ be the corresponding expectation operators. Moreover, let $B^d_T = e^{\int_0^t r^d_sds}$ and $B^f_T = e^{\int_0^t r^f_sds}$ be the respective  domestic and foreign money market account values at time $t$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
B^d_tE^Q\left(\frac{S_T-K}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) = 0.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
K = \frac{B^d_tE^Q\left(\frac{S_T}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{E^Q\left(\frac{B^d_t}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}= \frac{B^d_tE^Q\left(\frac{S_T}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{P^d(t, T)}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Let $Q^T$ be the domestic $T$-forward measure and $E^{Q^T}$ be the corresponding expectation operator. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dQ^T}\big|_{[t, T]} = \frac{B^d_T}{B^d_tP^d(t, T)}.
\end{align*}
From $(1)$,
\begin{align*}
K &= \frac{B^d_t E^Q\left(\frac{S_T}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{P^d(t, T)}\\
&=E^{Q^T}(S_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
E^{Q^T}(S_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = F_t(T).
\end{align*}
On the other hand, we note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dQ^f}\big|_{[t, T]} = \frac{B^d_TB^f_t S_t}{B^f_T B^d_tS_T}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
E^Q\left(\frac{S_T}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) &= E^{Q^f}\left(\frac{B^d_TB^f_t S_t}{B^f_T B^d_tS_T}\frac{S_T}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&=\frac{S_t}{B^d_t}E^{Q^f}\left(\frac{B^f_t}{B^f_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&=\frac{S_t}{B^d_t}P^f(t, T).
\end{align*}
Moreover, from $(1)$,
\begin{align*}
K &= \frac{B^d_t E^Q\left(\frac{S_T}{B^d_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{P^d(t, T)}\\
&=S_t \frac{P^f(t, T)}{P^d(t, T)}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
E^{Q^T}(S_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = F_t(T) = S_t \frac{P^f(t, T)}{P^d(t, T)}.\tag{2}
\end{align*}

However, we note that, with stochastic interest rates, generally,
\begin{align*}
E^{Q}(S_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \ne F_t(T).
\end{align*}

$$$$
As OP has already pointed out, Fromula $(2)$ can also be shown by no arbitrage argument. Specifically, at time $t$, while entering a forward contract with forward exchange rate $F_t(T)$, we borrow one unit domestic currency (which can be used to buy $\frac{1}{P^d(t, T)}$ units domestic zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$), convert into $\frac{1}{S_t}$ units foreign currency, and buy $\frac{1}{S_t P^f(t, T)}$ units foreign zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$. The net value of this trading strategy is zero.

At maturity $T$, in domestic currency, the above trading strategy has value $$F_t(T)\frac{1}{S_tP^f(t, T)}-\frac{1}{P^d(t, T)},$$ which should also have zero value. That is,
\begin{align*}
F_t(T) &=S_t \frac{P^f(t, T)}{P^d(t, T)}.
\end{align*}